# RestSharp Google's OAuth

Tags: c#, google-oauth, restsharp

If I use RestSharp for **grant_type=authorization_code** on Google's OAuth-Server, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\ngrant_type=authoriza\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

If I do the Request with Fiddler, everything is working, its also working with other OAuth-Servers.

RestRequest:

```
RestClient  restClient = new RestClient(@"https://www.googleapis.com/");
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(@"oauth2/v4/token", Method.POST);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-urlencoded");
restRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
restRequest.AddParameter("client_id", "id");
restRequest.AddParameter("client_secret", "secret");
restRequest.AddParameter("code", "authcode");
restRequest.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "redirectURI");
```

How to solve this issue? Why is this: **`\ngrant_type=authoriza\n^`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string should be added as a single paramater

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The payload is a single http request string it is NOT json format the response you get back however is in json format

content type should be

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Shouldn't RestSharp assemble that single encoded line from the parameters passed automatically?

Comment: no idea i have never used restsharp but it looks like its adding returns (\n) after each parm it should be stringing them together with &.   i normally use the google .net client library which handles all this for you.

Comment: Thank you, it was the Content-Type, just forgot "form"... that was the issue, thank you!